# Profiler/Flamegraph for NestJS applications/functions

Tags: nestjs, profiler

I have looked around for profilers for **NestJS** and not had much luck finding something specifically for NestJS. The couple I found were not well documented on how to implement and use and integrate in to a Jenkins pipeline.

I found TS-Node-Dev profiler that I used in IntelliJ and it shows a flamegraph but doesn't give info on the function call stack - how long did each function in the call stack take to execute.

Example: Fn A calls Fn B, which then calls Fn C.  How much time did each of these functions take to execute.

Do you know of any way to get a profiler working for NestJS that can display a flamegraph?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried https://clinicjs.org/flame?

Comment: Thanks.  I had looked at ClinicJS briefly but it did not mention anything about profiling NestJS applications so I did not try it out.  However, I will dive into it and see if it works for NestJS (do not need to profile NodeJS).

Comment: Did you find anything about it? Because I tried to and it works in general, but all my own NestJS functions are shown as [anonymous] and the file and line is always like example.js:1:1 what is not very useful...

Comment: Afraid not. We are facing the same issue and have not found any resolution.